# Empty std::vector<unique_ptr<AbstractStatement>> after function returns

Tags: c++, vector

I am working on a project where an AST-like tree is represented. As there is a lot of nesting involved, I am using smart pointers `unique_ptr` to save the references and avoid copies.

**Issue Description.** The vector `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractStatement>> blockStatements;` is a member of the `Block` class which represents a code block (e.g., statements in the then-branch of an if-statement). After adding statements to the `Block` object, they are added properly to the vector as I could confirm using CLion's debugger.
However, after returning from the function `generateAst` (see `main.cpp`), the vector is unexpectedly empty. See following image:

[image: CLion debugger]

A `Function` is passed to `generateAst` and modified there. The concerned `blockStatements` vector is embedded into the `Function` object as follows:

```
object Function
-- member std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractStatement>> body;
----- object If
------- member AbstractStatement *thenBranch;
---------- object Block
------------ member std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractStatement>> blockStatements;
--------------- (any AbstractStatement, e.g., VarAssignm [see main()])
```

The `Block` is implemented as follows:

```
// block.h --–----------------

class Block : public AbstractStatement {
public:

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractStatement>> blockStatements;

    Block();

    Block(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractStatement>> stat);

    void addStatement(std::unique_ptr<AbstractStatement> &&statement);

};

// block.cpp --–----------------

Block::Block() = default;

void Block::addStatement(std::unique_ptr<AbstractStatement> &&statement) {
    blockStatements.push_back(std::move(statement));
}

Block::Block(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractStatement>> stat) : blockStatements(std::move(stat)) {

}
```

I am adding elements to the `blockStatements` in the following way (btw. using `addStatement` results in the same loss of elements):

```cpp
void generateAst(Function *pFunction) {
    pFunction->name = "demoFunction";
    FunctionParameter paramX("X", "int");
    pFunction->addParameter(paramX);

    Block thenBlock;
    Variable varX("x");
    auto assignXtoX = std::make_unique<VarAssignm>("x", &varX);
    thenBlock.blockStatements.push_back(std::move(assignXtoX));
    auto ifStmt = std::make_unique<If>();
    ifStmt->thenBranch = std::move(&thenBlock);
    pFunction->body.push_back(std::move(ifStmt)); // this doesn't seem to work
    std::cout << "end of generateAst(...)" << std::endl; // f.body.at(0).thenBranch.size = 1 -> as expected
}

int main() {
    Function f;
    generateAst(&f);
    std::cout << "finished!" << std::endl; // f.body.at(0).thenBranch.size = 0  -> why?!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you really sure about `std::move(&thenBlock)`? Because `&thenBlock` will create a pointer to a ***local*** variable, a variable whose life-time end when the function returns (and destructing the object), making the pointer immediately invalid.

Comment: Same for `&varX`, you are storing the address of a function-local variable. It will be invalid as soon as the function returns.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see! Sorry, I am still a C++ beginner. What's the way to go then to avoid that objects get deleted after the function returns? Create a `unique_ptr` using `make_unique<Block>`?

Comment: Yes that's a good idea. At the very least you need to dynamically allocate the `thenBlock` one way or the other.

Comment: This code could be simplified a lot (and problems avoided) by using `std::variant` instead of subclass polymorphism and pointers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the suggestion! Could you kindly outline that briefly or point me to an example? Where exactly would it make sense to use `std::variant`? To get rid of the `AbstractStatement` base class?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and @Mat Thanks a lot for your note, specially because it might be pretty obvious for an experienced C++ dev. By using `unique_ptr` for every object instantiation in `generateAst` it works fine now  However, as mentioned by @KonradRudolph it is a complex and error-prone architecture. I think I will add it on CodeReview to get some feedback on how I could improve it.

Comment: @Patrick Correct. For inspiration, check out my [lisp.cpp project](https://github.com/klmr/lisp.cpp). It’s six years old and abandoned and doesn’t use C++14 (let alone C++17) yet, but it shows the general idea. The relevant declaration is in `value.hpp`, and the dispatch happens in `eval.cpp`. IIRC there are *no owning pointers* in the whole project.